# Mikrotik Sxt Роутер - Точка - точка

Tags: роутер, mikrotik

Настраиваю Mikrotik SXT. Нужно что-бы точка которая в которую включен интернет от провайдера работала как роутер и потом канал точка-точка до второго SXT.

Проблема 1.
На пк который стоит за локальным mikrotik интернет есть. Если прописать DNS провайдера. Если Поставить DNS 192.168.0.111 то интернета нет. На локальном Mikrotik интернета тоже нет. И не важно какие прописаны DNS 192.168.0.111 или провайдера.

Проблема 2.
Не могу сообразить как на локальном микротик сделать что-бы он при велючении DHCP раздавал DNS провайдера. Ну что-бы не прописывать их статически

Проблема 3.
Также у провайдера есть IPTV. Вроде все сделал по инструкции из интернета Установил пакет Multicats, создал 2 правила на фаерволе и 2 правила в IGMP прокси. И эта конфигурация успешно работает на другом mikrotik не SXT. Тут видимо из-за Бриджа нет. Чего-то я не дописал. Только не могу понять где

Конфиг главного SXT который подключен к интернету

```html
/interface wireless
set [ find default-name=wlan1 ] band=5ghz-a/n channel-width=20/40mhz-eC \
    disabled=no frequency=5320 frequency-mode=superchannel guard-interval=long \
    hw-retries=15 mode=bridge nv2-cell-radius=10 nv2-preshared-key=1234567890 \
    nv2-security=enabled radio-name=Master scan-list=5180 ssid=sss1 \
    tdma-period-size=1 tx-power=30 tx-power-mode=all-rates-fixed \
    wds-default-bridge=bridge1 wds-mode=dynamic wireless-protocol=nv2 wps-mode=\
    disabled
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether1 ] mac-address=<MAC>
/interface wireless nstreme
set wlan1 disable-csma=yes enable-nstreme=yes framer-policy=dynamic-size
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] authentication-types=wpa-psk,wpa2-psk eap-methods="" \
    group-ciphers=tkip,aes-ccm mode=dynamic-keys unicast-ciphers=tkip,aes-ccm \
    wpa-pre-shared-key=<KEY> wpa2-pre-shared-key=\
    <KEY>
/ip ipsec proposal
set [ find default=yes ] enc-algorithms=aes-128-cbc
/queue type
set 1 pfifo-limit=500
set 2 kind=pfifo pfifo-limit=500
/ip address
add address=192.168.0.111/24 interface=wlan1 network=192.168.0.0
/ip dhcp-client
add default-route-distance=0 dhcp-options=hostname,clientid disabled=no \
    interface=ether1
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=forward connection-state=established,related \
    log-prefix=""
add action=accept chain=input comment=IPTV1 log-prefix="" protocol=igmp
add action=accept chain=forward comment=IPTV2 dst-port=1234 log-prefix="" \
protocol=udp
add action=accept chain=input log-prefix="" protocol=icmp
add action=accept chain=input connection-state=established,related log-prefix=""
add action=drop chain=forward connection-state=invalid log-prefix=DROP
add action=drop chain=forward connection-nat-state=!dstnat connection-state=new in-interface=ether1 log-prefix=DROP
add action=drop chain=input in-interface=ether1 log-prefix=DROP
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat log-prefix="" out-interface=ether1
/routing igmp-proxy interface
add interface=wlan1
add alternative-subnets=0.0.0.0/0 interface=ether1 upstream=yes
/system leds
set 0 interface=wlan1
```

Конфиг локального mikrotik

```html
/interface bridge
add mtu=1500 name=bridge1
/interface wireless
set [ find default-name=wlan1 ] adaptive-noise-immunity=ap-and-client-mode ampdu-priorities=\
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 antenna-gain=30 band=5ghz-a/n channel-width=20/40mhz-eC dfs-mode=\
    no-radar-detect disabled=no frequency-mode=superchannel guard-interval=long hw-retries=15 mode=\
    station-bridge nv2-preshared-key=1234567890 nv2-security=enabled radio-name=Client ssid=sss1 \
    wds-default-bridge=bridge1 wds-mode=dynamic
/interface wireless nstreme
set wlan1 disable-csma=yes enable-nstreme=yes framer-policy=dynamic-size
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] authentication-types=wpa-psk,wpa2-psk eap-methods="" group-ciphers=\
    tkip,aes-ccm mode=dynamic-keys unicast-ciphers=tkip,aes-ccm wpa-pre-shared-key=\
    <KEY> wpa2-pre-shared-key=<KEY>
/queue type
set 1 pfifo-limit=500
set 2 kind=pfifo pfifo-limit=500
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether1
add bridge=bridge1 interface=wlan1
/ip address
add address=192.168.0.112 interface=bridge1 network=192.168.0.0
/ip dns
set servers=<Provider DNS>
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=forward disabled=yes log-prefix=""
/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=bridge1
add disabled=yes distance=1 gateway=192.168.0.111
/routing igmp-proxy interface
add interface=bridge1
add disabled=yes interface=ether1 upstream=yes
/system leds
set 0 interface=wlan1
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем решение нашлось как всегда в голове.
Необходимо было на интерфейсах vlan на обоих точках прописать IP адреса и все сразу заработало. 2-й пункт выпал. т.к. нужно было прописать set allow-remote-requests=yes
и dns теперь стоит 192.168.0.111 и исправно работает.